# How to trigger properly an action after popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have the following button which opens a popup:

```
<button type="button" id="btnBuscarCuenta" 
   onClick="javascript:AbrirPopUpBusqueda('id_AyudaCuentas',
              'pop_cuentas_contables.cfm','', '900px', '600px');AsignaCuentas();"> 
   <img src="../images/buscar.png" alt="Clic para buscar Cuenta Bancaria"/>
</button>
```

As you can see, the method which is calling the popup is called `AbrirPopUpBusqueda`. One of the parameters is `id_AyudaCuentas` is the hidden input that will receive the value after popup is closed.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_AyudaCuentas" id="id_AyudaCuentas"/>
```

After the input 'id_AyudaCuentas' gets the value, it should trigger a function AsignaCuentas() which only separates the value and separate them into other text inputs:

```
<cfinput id="id_Cuenta" name="id_Cuenta" type="text" value="#id_Cuenta#"  >
<cfinput id="id_SCuenta" name="id_SCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SCuenta#">
<cfinput id="id_SSCuenta" name="id_SSCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SSCuenta#">
<cfinput id="id_SSSCuenta" name="id_SSSCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SSSCuenta#">
```

The problem is that event is not triggered, or just trigger when you click the button again (which is undesirable behaviour). I've tried setting an `onBlur` or `onChange` attributes in the hidden input `id_AyudaCuentas` but it also doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I included the AsignaCuentas() function:

```
function AsignaCuentas()
 {
     if ($x('id_AyudaCuentas').value != '')
     {
         ArregloCuentas= $x('id_AyudaCuentas').value.split('|');
         $x('id_Cuenta').value= ArregloCuentas[0];                               
         $x('id_SCuenta').value= ArregloCuentas[1];
         $x('id_SSCuenta').value= ArregloCuentas[2];
         $x('id_SSSCuenta').value= ArregloCuentas[3];
    }
     ponerFocus('id_SSSCuenta');
}
```

Comment: First, look at the source code in the browser. using `<cfinput..>` (which I rather avoid as do most advanced CF folks) writes a great deal of Java script with custom "on the fly" naming to the HTML output. Load the _source code_ of your page into a plain HTML file and troubleshoot it with firebug or whatever. Then turn back to the CFML to see what needs to be done. My guess is you will see something to work with right away.

Comment: When a I wild javascript error appears, i usually watch in Chrome Console to debug, set breakpoints, etc. But i can't figure out what is going on here because there's no error. At this point i already know that the event is not triggering, so the function doesn't too.

Comment: I suspect there is no error because your cfinputs inplement their own JS functions that preempt your custom ones. that's what I'm getting at. View source to find out.

Comment: What is the code for `AbrirPopUpBusqueda`? Any chance it is returning false or doing something that might prevent the second function from triggering?

Comment: I don't think so, when a value is not selected in the popup, doesn't do anything. It's not problem of that AbrirPopUpBusqueda function

Comment: I tried this changing "hidden" input type with a "text", and it triggers the function when i set onBlur="AsignaCuentas()". I read somewhere that the problem is that hidden inputs can't be focused or unfocused, so that's the reason why never triggers using attributes like 'onChange' or 'onBlur'

Comment: Well that totally makes sense... how can they take mouse movements eh? :D Why not just hold your variables in a json string in Javascript, then pass them along when you post (throw them into your hidden field then).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [jQUery demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/1xewhepu/)

Notes:

- The jsfiddle sets a value to the hidden field and triggers the change event on that.
- I had to comment out `ponerFocus` since you didn't include that.
- I added a sample button to trigger the change since I didn't have the popup.
- Jquery's `.change()` won't trigger without user input. You can, however use `.trigger('change')` to trigger the event. Your popup can set the value of the hidden field and append `.trigger('change')`

Sample Form:

```
<form id="motherform">
    Main Field: <input type="hidden" name="id_AyudaCuentas" id="id_AyudaCuentas" value="a|b|c|d">
    <input type="button" value="Click this button to change hidden value." onclick="$('#id_AyudaCuentas').val('this|is|a|test').trigger('change')">
    <input id="id_Cuenta" name="id_Cuenta" type="text" value="#id_Cuenta#"  >
    <input id="id_SCuenta" name="id_SCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SCuenta#">
    <input id="id_SSCuenta" name="id_SSCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SSCuenta#">
    <input id="id_SSSCuenta" name="id_SSSCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SSSCuenta#">
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_AyudaCuentas").change(function(){
        ArregloCuentas = $('#id_AyudaCuentas').val();
        var AC_Array = ArregloCuentas.split('|');
        if (AC_Array.length == 4) {
            $('#id_Cuenta').val(AC_Array[0]);                                                            
            $('#id_SCuenta').val(AC_Array[1]);
            $('#id_SSCuenta').val(AC_Array[2]);
            $('#id_SSSCuenta').val(AC_Array[3]);
        }
         // ponerFocus('id_SSSCuenta');
    });
});
```

I hope you can work with this with your popup to achieve your desired results.

Comment: Great example. Just remember in the question example you would _also_ have a bunch of Javascript that starts with CF and sets up functions for all those CFINPUT tags.

Comment: It Didn't work, because there's a function in the popup that try to focus the element which receives the value, and as we already know, focus doesn't work in hidden inputs.

Since I'm not able to modify that function on the popup i did the following workaround:

-Instead a hidden input I declare a text input, with an style property "display:none". 
-When I click the button this input become visible with .show() jQuery function.
-After closing the popup,a onfocus event in the input will trigger the AsignaCuentas(), also this function now includes a .hide() to the input.
A little weird,but works

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try it this way:
Change your code. Instead of the following:

```
<cfinput id="id_Cuenta" name="id_Cuenta" type="text" value="#id_Cuenta#"  >
<cfinput id="id_SCuenta" name="id_SCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SCuenta#">
<cfinput id="id_SSCuenta" name="id_SSCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SSCuenta#">
<cfinput id="id_SSSCuenta" name="id_SSSCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SSSCuenta#">
```

Try this:

```
<cfoutput>
<input id="id_Cuenta" name="id_Cuenta" type="text" value="#id_Cuenta#"/>
<input id="id_SCuenta" name="id_SCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SCuenta#"/>
<input id="id_SSCuenta" name="id_SSCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SSCuenta#"/>
<input id="id_SSSCuenta" name="id_SSSCuenta" type="text" value="#id_SSSCuenta#"/>
</cfoutput>
```

As far as I can see the only reason you are using cfinput is because it automatically renders the #id_**# values. But you don't need it and it is *probably* what is messing up your clean JS.